# Magento 1.9 - How to Change Product Option in Configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am trying to read the products from excel and creating. Once I created a size/color variant (Size / Color configurable ) product programmatically how can I change this product after creating a Color and Size combo configurable product? Do you have any thoughts on this?

Please help me.